# Python: reading integers in a file and adding them to a list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that takes an open file as an argument, reads the integers in the file which are all on their own line, then creates a list of those integers. The function should stop reading the file when there is an empty line. This is what I am stuck on.

```
def load_ints(file):
    lst = []
    x = 1
    while x == 1:
        for line in file:
            if len(line.strip()) != 0:
                load = line.split()
                load = [int(i) for i in load]
                lst = lst + load
            else:
                x = 2
        x = 2
    return lst
```

the file I am testing it with looks like this:

```
  1
  0
  -12
  53
  1078

  Should not be read by load_ints!
```

```
len(line.strip()) != 0:
```

is not working,

it currently gives me a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Should'

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a `break` after the `x = 2`

```
        else:
            x = 2
            break
```

Otherwise, the `for` loop will keep iterating over the file. It has read the blank line, executed the `else` condition, then carried on processing lines. So it tries to process the 'Should...' line, and fails because 'Should...' is not an integer.

Also, I don't see why you have the `while` statement. The `for` loop should be enough to iterate over the file and process each line, and the `break` I've suggested will exit the loop when you hit the blank line.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers already point out the issue: you have to stop parsing the integers when encoutering the blank line.

Here's a one-liner using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), stopping when stripping the line yields an empty line & converting to integer:

```
import itertools

def load_ints(file):
    return [int(x) for x in itertools.takewhile(str.strip,file)]
```

result:

```
[1, 0, -12, 53, 1078]
```

So `itertools.takewhile` iterates on the `file` lines, and applies `strip` on each line. If the result is an empty string, it stops the iteration. Otherwise it continues so the line is converted to integer and added to the list comprehension.

The less lines you're writing in those cases, the less bugs you'll create with auxiliary variables & states.

Comment: Thanks. I also put this as an option but your params were smarter.

Comment: @AntonvBR thanks. Always try listcomp & avoid `map` & `lambda` when possible, specially if a list is the final result.

Comment: That's what I mean. I'm stuck with lambda in my head. However I thought map was efficient. list(map(..)) over a list comprehension. no?

Comment: if you have to use `lambda` then it kills the interest for `map`. But `list(map(int,...))` is also good since `int` is already a function. Besides, if the data is iterated upon, OP may not need to convert to `list`. So bar what I said about `map` in that case.

Comment: Yep, but although I like the takewhile approach I still think it is better to read row by row using next() and try to add int and handle exceptions as my answer shows.

Comment: let's say it's more flexible with a loop. list comprehensions can be limited if there are complex inputs (not here)

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file you get a generator. Instead of reading it all to memory we could use the while loop to feed us with 1 row at a time and break when condition is met (row is blank). This should be the most efficient solution.

```
data = """\
1
2
-10
1241

Empty line above"""

with open("test.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(data)

with open("test.txt") as f:
    data = []
    while True:
        row = next(f).strip()
        try:
            data.append(int(row))
        # Break if ValueError is raised (for instance blank line or string)
        except ValueError:
            break

data
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, -10, 1241]
```

If you want a compact solution we could use takewhile from itertools. But this won't handle any error.

```
from itertools import takewhile

with open("test.txt") as f:
    data = list(map(int,takewhile(lambda x: x.strip(), f)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not necessary the while.

```
def load_ints(file):
    lst = []
    for line in file:
        if len(line.strip()) != 0:
            load = line.split()
            load = [int(i) for i in load]
            lst.append(load)
        else:
            break

    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop reading the file when the line is empty, you have to break the `for` loop :

```
def load_ints(file):
    lst = []
    for line in file:
        if len(line.strip()) != 0:
            load = line.split()
            load = [int(i) for i in load]
            lst = lst + load
        else:
            break
    return lst
```

Comment: Your `break` statement breaks out of the `for` loop.
The `while` loop then checks for the given condition and skips entering the `for` loop an additional time. A bit of semantics, but I would probably not describe your code as breaking the while loop ... rather it breaks the `for` loop.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, I miss readed the code. And in fact, after reading it in more detail, the `while` loop is unuseful ...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `re` module:

```
import re
def load_ints(my_file):
    return list(map(int, re.findall('-?\d', my_file.read())))
```